# How do I optimize Javascript with Closure Compiler and keep function names?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I have a javascript-file (lib.js) and I want to use some of the 
functions in an web page but I don't want to load the full lib.js.

However, I have not figured out how to do what I want. I want to
use command line.

lib.js

```
function dog() {
    return 'Fido';
}

function famous_human() {
    return 'Winston';
}

function human() {
    return famous_human();
}
```

code-calling-functions-in-lib.js

```
alert(human());
```

Desired result, lib-compiled.js

```
function a() {return 'Winston';}function human() {return a();}
```

- Function dog is removed since I don't use it.
- Function famous_human is is optimized.
- Function human has its original name since I want to call it from other code.
- No code from code-calling-functions-in-lib.js

.

```
java -jar compiler.jar --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS --js lib.js --XXXXXXXX code-calling-functions-in-lib.js --js_output_file lib-compiled.js
```

Is there a simple answer to my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export human:

```
function human() {
    return famous_human();
}

window['human'] = human;
```

[More information on exports](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#export)

Since exporting symbols blocks dead-code elimination, a best practice is to keep the project-specific exports in a separate file and not included in your library.

## Example

### Library Source - liba.js

```
function dog() {
  return 'Fido';
}

function famous_human() {
  return 'Winston';
}

function human() {
  return famous_human();
}
```

### Project Specific Exports - project_exports.js

```
window['human'] = human;
```

### Compile command

```
java -jar compiler.jar \
  --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS \
  --js liba.js \
  --js project_exports.js \
  --js project_source.js \
  --js_output_file project_compiled.js
```

Comment: Ok, but can you be more specific? I might be really stupid but I do need an idiot proof example. I have read a lot and tried a lot of examples on this issue but I don't get it to work.

Comment: Yes @user2473324 As a first try to get it working you can put that line in `lib.js`. Try it out on http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Comment: @user2473324 When I compile the three function from your question with that extra export line I get the result: `window.human=function(){return"Winston"};`, which would allow you to call `human()` from other scripts, since `window` is the global context.

Comment: I believe @Chad Killingsworth is more familiar with Closure than me, so perhaps he could give some advice too.

Comment: @user2473324 There is too much to explain in a comment, so I added the example to the answer.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you. Now I understand how stupid I was in the first place. Without your example I don't know how long it would have taken me to solve the problem by myself.

Comment: Have done that now. Sorry about the delay but I'm new to ask question here. I usually find solutions to my problem in other peoples questions.